Recovering irrational number $\alpha$ from behavior of the sequence $ (\{ m\alpha \})_{m \geq 1}$
Given an irrational number $\alpha > 0$ (I specifically care about the case where $\alpha$ is a quadratic integer which is also a Pisot number, but the question can be asked in general), it is well known that if we define $c_m = \{ m\alpha\}$ where $\{ x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$, then the sequence $( c_m)_{m\geq 1}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.
Now, define two sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ as follows:
$$ a_n = \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} c_m, $$
$$ b_n = \min_{1\leq m \leq n} c_m. $$
These are a non-decreasing and a non-increasing sequence, respectively. The question is: can you recover the number $\alpha$ if you only know at which indices the sequences increase/decrease, but do not know the values of the sequences?
That is, do the sets $A_\alpha = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : a_{k} > a_{k-1}  \}, \, B_\alpha = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : b_k < b_{k-1} \}$ uniquely specify $\{  \alpha \}$ in the general case (they do not uniquely specify $\alpha$ since you can always take the trivial counterexamples $\alpha' = \alpha + M$, for $M\in \mathbb{N}$)? And in the particular case where $\alpha$ is a quadratic (irrational) Pisot number, do $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ uniquely specify $\alpha$ (among all such numbers)?
Any comments or pointers to relevant results would be appreciated, thanks!

I would take a look at J. Beck treatise Probabilistic Diophantine Approximation as it has a lot of discussion about the distribution of the irrational rotations - now it may be quite off from what you are interested as I think it focuses on quadratic irrationals a lot but has general stuff too; https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-10741-7

This is related to the three gaps theorem, which gives the values of the lengthes of the intervals of $[0,1]$ defined by $c_1,\ldots,c_n$. There are at most three different lengthes, which can be computed with the help of the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$.
View for example P. Alessandri, V. Berthé, Three distance theorems and combinatorics on words, Enseign. Math. (2) 44, no. 1-2, 103–132 (1998).
https://www.theoremoftheday.org/Docs/3dAlessandriBerthe.pdf
or
https://hal.science/hal-02272389v3
Let $(p_n/q_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be the sequence of convergents of $\alpha$, and $(d_n)_{n \ge 1}$ the sequence of partial quotients.
The first elements of $A_\alpha \cup\{1\}$ are $1,2,\ldots,d_1 = q_1$.
The first elements of $B_\alpha$ are $q_1+1,2q_1+1,\ldots,d_2q_1+1 = q_2$.
The next elements of $A_\alpha$ are $q_2+q_1,2q_2+q_1,\ldots,a_3q_2+q_1 = q_3$.
The next elements of $B_\alpha$ are $q_3+q_2,2q_3+q_2,\ldots,d_4q_3+q_2 = 
q_4$.
And so on.
From $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$, one can recover the sequence $(d_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of partial quotients, therefore $\alpha - \lfloor\alpha\rfloor$ through its continued fraction expansion.

I think in the last sentence should be ${\alpha}$ instead of $\alpha$

Based on this, it also follows that $A_{\alpha}$ alone can determine ${\alpha}$, the same with $B_{\alpha}$ alone.

Thanks for the answer and sources! Accepting this answer.

$\varphi$ and its square $\varphi + 1$ are both Pisot numbers and quadratic integers, so their sequences are identical. This already gives a counter-example on the question relating to determining uniquely $\alpha$ based on its sequences, even among the Pisot quadratic integers.
On the determination of the fractional part of the number based on its sequences, I have only a sketch of proof:
Be $x$ and $y$ $\in (0,1)$, with $x \ne y$. We show their sets $A_x \ne A_y$ and $B_x \ne B_y$. WLOG, let's assume $x>y$
Case 1 : $x \gt 1/2$ and $y \lt 1/2$
We notice that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \in A_x \implies n \notin B_x$ and $n \in B_x \implies n \notin A_x$
Then,  $ 1 \ge 2y \gt y  \implies 2 \in A_y $. On the other hand, $1 \le 2x \lt x+1 \lt 2 \implies \{2x\} < \{x\} \implies 2 \in B_x$. This means $A_x \ne A_y$ and $B_x \ne B_y$
Case 2 : $0 \lt x-y \lt 1/2$
I suspect we can prove that there is a new element in $B_x$ with no counterpart in $B_y$ inferior to $\frac {1}{x-y}$, but the proof is done better and more generally by the other answer
